# How can I create a custom Style Cop rule with strict inheritance checking?

Tags: c#, stylecop

I would like to create a Style Cop rule that returns an error if a class *directly* inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`. I'm able to get an instance of `StyleCop.CSharp.Class` representing whatever class I'm looking at but from there I'm at a bit of a loss. The Class object (StyleCop's, not System) has a `Declaration` attribute which would allow me to get at everything in the declaration... which includes the inherited class name. But that does not necessarily guarantee uniqueness.

Detecting this is easy enough:

```
public class Foobar : System.Web.UI.Page {}
```

But a circumstance like this becomes nasty...

```
using Page = System.Web.UI.Page;
public class Foobar : Page {}
```

Especially when you have **other** classes with declarations like this

```
using Page = Company.Some.Thing.Page;
public class Foobar : Page {}
```

How can I create a rule with strict type checking that doesn't get tripped up by classes with the same name in different namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

It's a job for FxCop, not Stylecop, as you're interested in the **compiled** code, not the **source** code.

You simply would have to do a bit of reflection (well, *introspection* actually) to get the list of types that inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`, then check if their `BaseType` is `System.Web.UI.Page` or not.

Here's a basic example with reflection:

```
    internal class Test2 : Test
    {
    }

    internal class Test : Program
    {
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
            {
                if (typeof(Program).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                {
                    if (type.BaseType == typeof(Program))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("strict inheritance for {0}", type.Name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("no strict inheritance for {0}", type.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

---

```
no strict inheritance for Program
strict inheritance for Test
no strict inheritance for Test2
```